# How to reorder the flex items when resizing the screen?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

By using the media query and flexbox, I can only rearrange the order of the content in the second row. I want to switch order from the first row to the second row but I cannot find the solution.

I tried to change the different order number and it has no effect at all.

```css
.item {
  width: 99%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  div#item {
    order: 0
  }
  div#item1 {
    order: 3
  }
  div#item2 {
    order: 4
  }
  div#item3 {
    order: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item" id="item"></div>
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="item1" id="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2" id="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3" id="item3"></div>
</div>
```

When resizing the screen, I want to change the order between the two rows. For example, when resizing the screen, the purple and blue change position each other. How to do it?

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first row and second row are *different flexboxes* - you can wrap `item` into the container of the second row and using a *wrapping flexbox* using `flex-wrap: wrap`. After the first row is filled and if space is not left in the row, the *flex items* drop to the next row.

Try changing `order` for the first row below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex; /* flexbox container */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* wrap the flexbox */
}

.item {
  width: 99%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  display: flex;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
}

.item3 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  div#item {
    order: 5; /* see changed order below 500px */
  }
  div#item1 {
    order: 3;
  }
  div#item2 {
    order: 4;
  }
  div#item3 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item" id="item"></div>
  <div class="item1" id="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2" id="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3" id="item3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, this works perfectly. Appreciate your help, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Simply consider one flexbox container for all your element like below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container  > * {
  height: 100px;

}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

.item1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc(100%/3);
}

.item2 {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: calc(100%/3);
}

.item3 {
  background-color: red;
  width: calc(100%/3);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container > div {
    width:100%;
  }
  
  div.item {
    order: 2
  }
  div.item1 {
    order: 3
  }
  div.item2 {
    order: 4
  }
  div.item3 {
    order: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
```